# how to get key and value of object whose values are not equal to null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
let data = {
      toDate: this.state.toDate,
      fromDate: this.state.fromDate,
      filteredEntityText: null,
      options: "negative",
      searchTerm: null
    };
```

From the above object I want to generate a new object that only has key value pairs whose values are not null.

The expected result should look like this:

```
let newData = {
    toDate: this.state.toDate,
    fromDate: this.state.fromDate,
    options: "negative"
};
```

Here I have used a static example of `data` object, the null values may differ later. Basically I want a new object with key value pairs whose value is not `null`.
Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: Use `Object.keys(data)` to get an array of `data`'s keys.

Comment: please share what you've tried and explain what's not working, and we can help to debug it. SO isn't a free code-writing service

Comment: @RobinZigmond I tried `Object.values(data).filter(item => item !== null);` this but the result is not as expected as I get values only.

Comment: @BirajGautam
Which function you have tried? As my answer will help you in future where you need to remove nested null values as well.
Example, data = {a: {
b: null
}}
so it will remove null as well. and in my answer if you do not want to remove empty string you can remove that condition from if.
Using reducer function doesn't make sense here, as in Mayank's answer. It will consume more memory, don't think for temporary solution, think of time complexity, space complexity. And future expects as well, which will solve your many problems in future codes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This all will help you to remove nested null items as well.
Using some ES6 / ES2015:
Below some example will modify data object directly or if you want to create duplicate object with removed nulls you can call functions given below it will return new object.

If you don't like to create an extra function and remove the items 'inline'.

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(k => (!data[k] && data[k] !== undefined) && delete data[k]);
```

Same, written as a function.

```
const removeEmpty = (data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => (!data[k] && data[k] !== undefined) && delete 
       data[k]);
  return data;
};
```

This function uses recursion to delete items from nested objects as well:

```
const removeEmpty = (data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(k =>
    (data[k] && typeof data[k] === 'object') && removeEmpty(data[k]) ||
    (!data[k] && data[k] !== undefined) && delete data[k]
  );
  return data;
};
```

Same as function before but with ES7 / 2016 Object.entries:

```
const removeEmpty = data => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(
    k => !data[k] && data[k] !== undefined && delete data[k]
  );
  return data;
};
```

Same as third example but in plain ES5:

```
function removeEmpty(data) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(data[key]) ||
    (data[key] === '' || data[key] === null) && delete data[key]
  });
  return data;
};
```

Comment: I tried this one: `Object.keys(data).forEach(k => (!data[k] && data[k] !== undefined) && delete data[k]);`
and it gave me `undefined`. As you mentioned, your solution works on nested values as well, I will be sure to use them in the future when I require it.

Comment: @BirajGautam, your data objected is updated now. Print the data object after executing this code.

Comment: @BirajGautam, this line will help you directly use data object without initialising new 
 useless object.

Comment: oh, I didnt' quite catch that before, sorry about the confusion, and your solution works like a charm.

Comment: @BirajGautam And this syntax are ES6 and a better syntax. So instead of going with normal for loops, try to have practice of forEach and all this things. Which will be definitely help you in coming days.
And because of your confusion you dis-Approved my answer, which has more scope to learn with proper explanation.

Comment: Let me know if further clarification required, or any JS help required.

Answer (score 6):

You can try filtering [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const data = {
  toDate: {},
  fromDate: {},
  filteredEntityText: null,
  options: 'negative',
  searchTerm: null
};

const newData = {};
Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
  .forEach(([key, value]) => (newData[key] = value));

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `for...in` loop

```js
let data = {
  toDate: 'toDate',
  fromDate: 'fromDate',
  filteredEntityText: null,
  options: "negative",
  searchTerm: null
};
let newData = {};
for(var k in data){
  if(data[k] != null)
    newData[k] = data[k];
}
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This is my preferred approach, but I dislike the simple `if(data[k])` because that would exclude properties with values like `0` and `''` which the OP may well want. They only mentioned removing `null`, so I think `if (data[k] !== null)` is a better fit.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, you are right, updated the answer, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the expected result:

```js
let data = {
  toDate: "abc",
  fromDate: "cde",
  filteredEntityText: null,
  options: "negative",
  searchTerm: null
};

var newObj = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, el) => {
  // removing all the key-value pairs where value=null
  if(data[el] !== null)
    acc[el] = data[el];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log('newObj', newObj);
```

Comment: I make the same comment here is I did on another answer: this will remove all properties with "falsy" values, which isn't what the OP asked for - they may want to keep eg. `0` or empty string values. (And on a personal level I prefer to use a loop here than `reduce`. even though in general I like the functional programming style. I just find the loop more explicit. But that's a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: It will not remove the nested elements, Like data: {
a: 'Hi',
b: null,
c: '',
d: {
 e: 'Hello',
 f: null,
 g:''
}
}

So output should be:
data: {
a: 'Hi',
d: {
 e: 'Hello'
}
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let data = {
      toDate: this.state.toDate,
      fromDate: this.state.fromDate,
      filteredEntityText: null,
      options: "negative",
      searchTerm: null
    };

  let giveOriginal = (data){
     let originalHolder = {}
     for(let key in data){
        if(data[key]){
           originalHolder[key] = data[key]
         }
      }
    return originalHolder;
  }

 //call giveOriginal 
 giveOriginal(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

First `iterate` through that array of objects using `forEach`,then check for `data.searchTerm !== null`.
This is a working solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toDate: new Date(),
    fromDate: new Date()
  };
  searches = [
    {
      toDate: this.state.toDate,
      fromDate: this.state.fromDate,
      filteredEntityText: null,
      options: "negative",
      searchTerm: null
    },
    {
      toDate: this.state.toDate,
      fromDate: this.state.fromDate,
      filteredEntityText: null,
      options: "negative",
      searchTerm: "microsoft"
    },
    {
      toDate: this.state.toDate,
      fromDate: this.state.fromDate,
      filteredEntityText: null,
      options: "negative",
      searchTerm: "apple"
    }
  ];
  render() {
    let results = [];
    this.searches.forEach(data => {
      if (data.searchTerm !== null) results.push(data);
    });
    console.log(results);
    return (
      <div>
        {results.map((data, index) => (
          <span key={index}>{data.searchTerm}, </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```